# How to use replaceall to remove all blank space with hypens in apex

Tags: apex

I am trying to replace a spaces within a string with hypen.

For example

'this is a sample'

should be

'this-is-a-sample'

.`replace('/\s+/g', '-')` gives an error

> Invalid string literal '/\s+/g'. Illegal character sequence '\s' in
>   string literal.

Comment: I think that's pretty close, except one doesn't need to use forwardslash `/` delimiters... and backslashes may be escaped. So more like this: `.replaceAll('\\s+', '-')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\` is always an escape character.

- To use the regex `\s`, you need to use `\\s`.
- To use a literal `\`, use `\\\\`.

Answer (score 8):

why don't you use the replace method and pass in space (' ') & hyphen (-) as parameters. it will replace each space in the string with a hyphen as you expect.

```
string test = 'this is a space';
string newtest = test.replace(' ','-');
system.debug(newtest);
```

quick try in dev console anonymous window with debug log

[image]

Comment: This only works "as expected" if they only mean to remove "space" (0x20), and not other forms of whitespace, like tab (0x09), line feed (0x0a), and carriage return (0x0d).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove white space you can use this

```
string test = 'this is a space';
string newtest = test.replaceAll('\\s+','-');
system.debug(newtest);
```

Otherwise you wont have to use a regular expression. Use simply use this code:

```
string test = 'this is a space';
string newtest = test.replace(' ','-');
system.debug(newtest);
```