# Replace a word with bracket

Tags: apex

I need to replace `Where` with `Where (`

Replace each `where+space` with `where+space+open bracket`.

Please suggest me how to do this in Apex code. Is this possible without Matcher Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the replace method:

```
query = query.replace(' WHERE ', ' WHERE (');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String class method `replaceAll()` to do this.

related question  link: [How to use replaceall to remove all blank space with hypens in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72029/how-to-use-replaceall-to-remove-all-blank-space-with-hypens-in-apex)

```
string test = 'this is a space where';
string newtest = test.replaceAll('where ','where (');
system.debug(newtest);
```